# How to exclude a directory in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-fabric

I need to exclude files that are used in the github readme from build as they are causing the file size to be way too large. I tried adding this to my `build.gradle` but the files are still in the build.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources{
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude ("main/resources/assets/playtimer/github/**")
        }
    }
}
```